# multiple text colors in fabricJS

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there any way of adding more than one text color to a single Text or iText element in FabricJS? I am trying to use it to create a poster and the text needs different colors in the same paragraph.

Comment: Can you explain bit more http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink like this

Comment: Yes like that, but I cant find any code anywhere to actually do the color or style changes mid wayt through a text object

Comment: use [styles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#styles) property, to show differnet style for different characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const text1 = new fabric.Text('hello  1', {
  fontSize: 30,
  fill: 'white'
});

const group = new fabric.Group([text1], {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
});


group.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Text('hello world 32323234242323232323', {
  fontSize: 30,
  fill: 'red',
  left: group.getWidth() + 10,
  top: group.get('top'),
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'center'
}));
canvas.add(group);
```

Here is a codepen
https://codepen.io/pabloformoso/pen/YPYoqL

Comment: Nice work around, but not what I want as the user needs to be able to edit all text in one go using one object